# When to use strict mode in MySql or MariaDB

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I can find plenty of information on what strict mode does in MySql and MariaDB, but nothing on when to use it.  This is common sense to a degree, but I would still like to have some general guidelines.  For example, perhaps you:

- Always use strict mode
- Never use strict mode
- Always use strict mode on tables that have financial data
- etc

Comment: So you want someone to re-summarize this page? http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sql-mode-strict

Comment: Always use strict mode.  That is, until you get fed up with its restrictions.  The mode is there to help you, but it may be painful.

Comment: Thanks Rick.  Do you want to make that an answer and I will accept it?

Answer (score 7):

First, from [MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sql-mode-strict):

> Strict mode controls how MySQL handles invalid or missing values in data-change statements such as INSERT or UPDATE. A value can be invalid for several reasons. For example, it might have the wrong data type for the column, or it might be out of range. A value is missing when a new row to be inserted does not contain a value for a non-NULL column that has no explicit DEFAULT clause in its definition. (For a NULL column, NULL is inserted if the value is missing.) Strict mode also affects DDL statements such as CREATE TABLE.

So, as @rick-james said: *Always use strict mode. That is, until you get fed up with its restrictions. The mode is there to help you, but it may be painful.*

Strict mode is also [default on MariaDB](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/sql-mode/#strict-mode) since >10.2.3.

- **Get current mod**e: `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'sql_mode';`
- **Disable**: `mysql> SET sql_mode = '';`
- **Enable**: `mysql> SET sql_mode = 'STRICT_ALL_TABLES';` (or `STRICT_TRANS_TABLES`).

For permanent change edit `/etc/mysql/my.conf`, `[mysqld]` section, `sql_mode=` variable.